# git prevents to make push although nobody touched remote branch

Tags: git, push, pull

We have a quite simple workflow in git: the dev branch and the featured branches. As working on the feature branch is finished, we make rebase on dev and then push. But sometimes git prevent to make a push, although I know for sure that my changes on the feature branch are last ones. It claims I make pull first. And then it gets my previous version of the branch from the remote repo.
Actually, I can make a forced push, but I don't think, this is the best solution. 
Unfortunately, it is yet difficult to be sure what causes this. Presumably, someone also takes my branch, works on it, then makes rebase on dev. But those changes, in fact, are implemented earlier than mine ones. 
So, I suppose someone met such a case already (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are rebasing your local feature branch, then the only option you have is a forced push.

```
git push -f
```

But, this method is not recommended if there are other people working on the feature branch, because, then they will have force pull the changes.

Rebasing effectively re-writes the history of your feature branch. That is why you have to force push.

Another option you can use, is to not rebase at all. You can always `merge` the commits in dev to your feature branch. This will ensure that you can use a normal push to update the remote and all other users of feature branch can also pull without any trouble.